# segmentation fault to create malloc array of node

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I'm trying to create a function `path()`, which would return an array of node pointers with the path of node when a find a element within the tree. I tried to do with recursion, but I don't know what is wrong, the function path have a signature: `Node *a`, the binary tree, `int v`, the value to find, and `int *p` like as a counter of visited nodes.

Here's my code:

```
typedef struct nodo {
  int v;
  struct nodo *left, *right;
} Nodo;

Nodo **path(Nodo *a, int v, int *p) {
  (*p)++;
  Nodo **r = NULL;
  if (a == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (a->v == v) {
    r = (Nodo**)malloc((*p)*sizeof(Nodo*));
    r[(*p)-1] = a;
    return r;
  }

  else if (a->v < v) {
    Nodo **r = path(a->right, v, p);
    r[(*p)-1] = a;
    return r;
  }
  else if (a->v > v) {
    Nodo **r = path(a->left, v, p);
    r[(*p)-1] = a;
    return r;
  }
  return r;
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't increment `(*p)++` before you check whether `a == NULL`.

Comment: which line does it crash on? run it in a debugger to find out

Comment: when the code scope `r[(*p)-1] = a` after `malloc` call

Comment: I'm assuming `rama()` is `path()`? You only allocate memory when you actually found the value, which means that all the previous navigation references `NULL` pointer returned by `path()`. I'm guessing that's your first crash.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Is your question, "how do you figure out what caused a segmentation fault"? What debugger are you using?

Comment: The memory location `*p` is used by all recursions, but your code only ever increments it, never decrements it. I think this is the cause of your problem. I also think it would be easier to pass the depth as a number instead of as a pointer to a location holding a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your original code seems to be that the location holding the current depth is shared between all recursions, and it is only ever incremented, never decremented. I think a cleaner approach is to pass the depth as an actual number, rather than as a pointer to a shared depth location, as in the following code:

```
typedef struct nodo {
  int v;
  struct nodo *left, *right;
} Nodo;

Nodo **path(Nodo *a, int v, int depth) {
  Nodo **r;
  if (a == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (a->v == v) {
    r = malloc((depth+1)*sizeof(Nodo*));
  }
  else if (a->v < v) {
    r = path(a->right, v, depth+1);
  }
  else {
    r = path(a->left, v, depth+1);
  }
  if (r != NULL) {
    r[depth] = a;
  }
  return r;
}
```

The initial call should use 0 for the depth, for example: `p = path(node, value, 0);`.

To avoid having to pass 0 in the initial call, the recursive part of the function could be factored out as follows:

```
Nodo **path_(Nodo *a, int v, int depth) {
  Nodo **r;
  if (a == NULL) {
    return NULL;
  }
  if (a->v == v) {
    r = malloc((depth+1)*sizeof(Nodo*));
  }
  else if (a->v < v) {
    r = path_(a->right, v, depth+1);
  }
  else {
    r = path_(a->left, v, depth+1);
  }
  if (r != NULL) {
    r[depth] = a;
  }
  return r;
}

Nodo **path(Nodo *a, int v) {
  return path_(a, v, 0);
}
```

Then the initial call can be, for example: `p = path(node, value);`.

Comment: thanks, now i understand